# How to access data inside Dialog Builder's inner class?

Tags: java, android

This is more of a Java question, i believe. I would like to access myBundle from within the OnClickListener. Currently, i am getting this compiler error - Cannot refer to a non-final variable dataSend inside an inner class defined in a different method. Is there any way to achieve what i want to do? Thanks. Relevant piece of code....

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle myBundle) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DELETE:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Oh My God", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    executeDelete(myBundle);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: You should accept Anthony Chatellier's answer

Answer (score 1):

Just make your variable final.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, final Bundle myBundle) {

}
```

Comment: myBundle is a variable. Can't make it final. Any other ways to achieve this? If not, i will redesign my initial design so that i don't have to send in the data via bundle and instead have the executeDelete access the same data via some other means like setting private variables at the activity level.

Comment: Why do you say you can't make it final ? Do you event tried it ?

Comment: myBundle needs to be a variable. final would make it well, FINAL

Comment: Do you really know what "final" means ? If you don't understand this keyword, go to google, you'll find plenty of answers. I've spent time answering your question, so please, read my answer and try to understand it. Write the code I submitted to you and test it to see if it works. If you think my response is not correct, please argue, or give us other parts of your code that explain what you say.

Answer (score 1):

Put `final` keyword in front of your `dataSend` declaration (which does not seem in the code you've pasted.

Comment: myBundle needs to be a variable. final would make it well, FINAL

Comment: dude FINAL does not mean that you can't change its contents. you can't change the reference. do it.